# How could I update message from difference socket.io event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io

I am using the api with difference event `channelName1` and `channelName2`

```
//...this the realtime record
socket.on(channelName1, message => {
      console.log(channelName1, message1);
      //this return single item list in realtime`[{"price":100,"size":0.001}]`
 });

//realtime snapshot collection of records
socket.on(channelName2, message => {
   console.log(channelName2, message2);
   //this return the collection `[{"price":100,"size":0.01}, {"price":200,"size":0.02} ]`
   $('#live').text(message2)
});
```

I want to want to update size of `message2` if I found the `price":100` is present in the collection `message2`, so the after update message2 will

`[{"price":100,"size":0.001}, {"price":200,"size":0.002} ]`

anyone could you guide me how I can do this update from channelName1 to ChannelName2 data?

Comment: your question is a little unclear, if you need a function/callback variable/result in a anouther function make a variable which both have access to. i.e make a variable called *realtime*, then check in channelName2 with a loop for -> item.price == realtime.price -> push(item) etc

Comment: can you help to provide some sample code of doing this

Comment: i want update 'size' in messag2 which price is 100 by 'size' in message1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a matter of saving the websocket payloads to objects created in a more "global" scope.

```
// since these are defined outside of the websocket event handlers
// they are available to each
var payload1 = [];
var payload2 = [];

const combinePayloads = () => {
    if (payload1[0].price === payload2[0].price) {
        // merge values if prices are the same
        let combinedArray = payload1.concat(payload2);
        console.log(combinedArray);
    }
};

socket.on(channelName1, message => {
    payload1 = message;
    combinePayloads();
});
socket.on(channelName2, message => {
    payload2 = message;
    combinePayloads();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to store the single items somewhere and when the collection arrives you need to:

1. Process each item of the collection using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
2. For each item, try to [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) it in the stored single items.
3. If found, change the size.

I have also included a record in the collection that cannot be found so you can see what happens there: it remains unchanged.

Ignore the small changes I made to simulate the sockets. Hopefully you can see the big picture of what I'm doing.

Hope this helps and happy coding.

```js
// Stores each single item that arrives.
let singleItems = [];

// ...this is the realtime record.
function socketOn1(channelName1, message1) {
  console.log(channelName1, message1);

  // Store each single item as it arrives.
  singleItems.push(message1[0]);
};

// realtime snapshot collection of records
function socketOn2(channelName2, message2) {
  console.log(channelName2, message2);

  // For each element in the collection, find
  // the same record in the single items and
  // if found, update the price.
  results = message2.map((elem) => {
    found = singleItems.find(
      (single) => single.price === elem.price
    )
    if (found) {
      elem.size = found.size
    }
    return elem
  })

  console.log('results:')
  console.log(results)
};


// This stuff just simulates stuff arriving to sockets.
// You can ignore it if you want. But look at the order
// in which they are called.

let singleItemsMock = [{
    "price": 100,
    "size": 0.01
  },
  {
    "price": 50,
    "size": 0.02
  },
  {
    "price": 25,
    "size": 0.03
  },
  {
    "price": 10,
    "size": 0.04
  }
]

let collectionMock = [{
    "price": 100,
    "size": 0.001
  },
  {
    "price": 50,
    "size": 0.002
  },
  {
    "price": 13,
    "size": 0.005
  }
]

socketOn1(null, [singleItemsMock[0]])
socketOn1(null, [singleItemsMock[1]])
socketOn1(null, [singleItemsMock[2]])
socketOn1(null, [singleItemsMock[3]])

socketOn2(null, collectionMock)
```

Answer (score 4):

you can store channel1's data in hashMap and loop over channel2's data to check if there is an entry in the hashmap and return the item according to that.

```
const channel1HashMap = {};

//...this the realtime record
socket.on(channelName1, message => {
   console.log(channelName1, message1);
   dataHandler(message1, null);
});

//realtime snapshot collection of records
socket.on(channelName2, message => {
   console.log(channelName2, message2);
   const data = dataHandler(null, message2);
   updateView(data);
});

dataHandler = (message1, message2) => {
  const channel2Data = [];
  if(Array.isArray(message1)) {
    message1.forEach((message)=> {
       channel1HashMap[message.price] = message;
    });
  } else if(Array.isArray(message2)) {
    message2.forEach((message)=> {
      if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(channel1HashMap, message.price)){
        channel2Data.push(channel1HashMap[message.price]);
      } else {
        channel2Data.push(message);
      }
    });
  }
  return channel2Data;
}

updateView = (data) => {
  $('#live').text(data)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
socket.on(channelName1, message => {
  console.log(channelName1, message1);
  //this return single item list in realtime`[{"price":100,"size":0.001}]`
  var t = $('#live').text(message2)
  var text = JSON.parse(t)
  text[1].price = message[0].price
  $('#live').text(JSON.stringify(text))
  });
```